# Issue returning proper mouse cords

Tags: autohotkey

In this problem setXTowerLocation() is called, a message box than appears after exiting the message box the function getXCords() is called in which it continuously scans checking the keyState of Lbutton once it detects that its pushed down the getxCords() function returns the x value of the cords of the mouse, which in turned gets set to a global variable in the setXTowerLocation() function before returning and displaying the x cord in a message box. Every time i run it the message box comes up blank, i have tested aspects of the code and they all seem to work individually so i believe it must be an error in syntax?

The ending message box is only for testing purposes. Thanks in advance :)

```
SendMode Input

Global xTowerLocation =

setXTowerLocation()
MsgBox, 0, MessageBox, %xTowerLocation%

getxCords()
{
    xCord = 
    Loop,
    {
        GetKeyState, state, Lbutton
        if(state = "D")
        {
            MouseGetPos, xx, yy
            xCord := %xx%
            return
        }
    }
return xCord
}

setXTowerLocation() {
    MsgBox, 0, MessageBox, Begin?
    IfMsgBox OK
        xTowerLocation := getxCords()
return
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, syntax error in that xCord is referenced to a variable named after the contents (the mouse coord).  Fix these two lines in `getxCords()` so xCord holds the value of the variable xx as follows:

```
        xCord := xx
        return xCord
```

And then no `xCord` on that later `return` (at end of the function).

EDIT:  For even more fun, make the above `xCord` line as follows:

```
        xCord := "x= " . xx . " , y= " . yy
```

Comment: Works like a charm thank you this is my first time doing AHK so still getting the hang of the syntax. If you don't mind i'd love to know what's going on in (xCord := "x= " . xx . " , y= " . yy) looks much simpler but i am a little lost on how it works.

Comment: `xCord` is a variable, and it is set to the _expression_ that follows. Since we are doing expressions, variables are presumed.  So, first comes a literal text element (text elements need to be quoted), "`x= `" then the value held in `xx` then another text element and the value of `yy`.  This gives a result like this: `x= 651 , y= 453` which provides both mouse coordinates.  The "`.`" (dots) are just AHK way of concatenating these elements together.